# Event/delegate for undo button on iPad keyboard

Tags: iphone, ipad, uikeyboard

I need to treat the event when someone presses the undo button on the iPad keyboard. I've checked and none of the delegate methods are called. Did anyone have the same issue?

Comment: On the ipad numeric keyboard there is an undo button. I want to know programatically when it is pressed.

Comment: may i know y the requirement happend..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. Add action for your text field:

```
[textField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

Now you can handle this event in `textFieldValueChanged:(UITextField *)aTextField`